# How to access minimized program without re-enable the Windows 7 notification area?

Tags: windows-7, notification-area

I have disabled the notification area or system tray in Windows 7 using group police (gpedit.msc). Now all notification icons are gone. Now I want to access some application which  Minimize to system tray. Is there any way to access those minimized program without re-enable the notification area?

Answer (score 0):

Look into opening the Task Manager » Applications/Processes and look for the program. Try opening the program through this.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running the app again? Many apps that do not allow multiple instances will simply bring to front/maximise/focus the existing app window/running instance if run again (for example uTorrent behaves this way unless /recover is specified as a command-line argument).